# Vue.js 2: computed not updating on change in data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
  <h3>My identicon generator</h3>
  <div>
    input:
    <input v-on:input="onInput"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    output:

    <div v-html="identicon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    textInput: '',
  },
  computed: {
    identicon: function() {
      console.log('new identicon for:', this.textInput);
      return jdenticon.toSvg(this.textInput, 200);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput: (e) => {
      this.textInput = e.target.value;
      console.log('is it set?', this.textInput);
    }
  }
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxNrNP

I expected the identicon to get updated on entering text in the input field. `console.log(is it set?', this.textInput)` runs correctly and the latest value of `textInput` is shown in the console. However, `console.log('new identicon for:', this.textInput)` runs only at the time of loading the page and does not run ever again which leads to the identicon remaining as it is. Why is the computed method not being called when `textInput` changes? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes and now it works.
1.- Change the data object into a function which returns an object
2.- Change the @input to a v-model

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      textInput: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    identicon() {
      console.log('new identicon for:', this.textInput);
      return jdenticon.toSvg(this.textInput, 200);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput: (e) => {
      this.textInput = e.target.value;
      console.log('is it set?', this.textInput);
    }
  }
});
```

Works as expected.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwKazg?editors=1111

However I also fixed your organitzation, this works too, and you problem had to do with the scope of your onInput method and identicon computed property.

This works, I changed them all to ES6 functions.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    textInput: '',
  },
  computed: {
    identicon() {
      console.log('new identicon for:', this.textInput);
      return jdenticon.toSvg(this.textInput, 200);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      this.textInput = e.target.value;
      console.log('is it set?', this.textInput);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: In the second example it's just how the function is defined :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both solutions work.. You're right, it was a scoping issue indeed!